# reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' when sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm

The question is from [meeting rooms](https://leetcode.com/problems/meeting-rooms/), which asks you determine if there is conflict between any (start time, end time) pairs

I wrote a lambda function to sort vector based on its first element.

```
    bool canAttendMeetings(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(),
             [](vector<int> a, vector<int>b) {
                 return a[0] - b[0];
             });
        for(int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            if(intervals[i][0] < intervals[i - 1][1])   return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

---

**Error**

> runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'
>   (stl_vector.h)

---

*I notice the error is caused by `a[0] - b[0]`.
If I change it to `a[0] < b[0]`, problems are solved.
What is happening here?*

---

**The input causing the error is**

```
[[64738,614406],[211748,780229],[208641,307338],[499908,869489],
[218907,889449],[177201,481150],[123679,384415],[120440,404695],
[191810,491295],[800783,826206],[165175,221995],[420412,799259],
[484168,617671],[746410,886281],[765198,792311],[493853,971285],
[194579,313372],[119757,766274],[101315,917883],[557309,599256],
[167729,723580],[731216,988021],[225883,752657],[588461,854166],
[231328,285640],[772811,869625],[892212,973218],[143535,306402],
[336799,998119],[65892,767719],[380440,518918],[321447,558462],
[54489,234291],[43934,44986],[11260,968186],[248987,707178],
[355162,798511],[661962,781083],[149228,412762],[71084,953153],
[44890,655659],[708781,956341],[251847,707658],[650743,932826],
[561965,814428],[697026,932724],[583473,919161],[463638,951519],
[769086,785893],[17912,923570],[423089,653531],[317269,395886],
[412117,701471],[465312,520002],[168739,770178],[624091,814316],
[143729,249836],[699196,879379],[585322,989087],[501009,949840],
[424092,580498],[282845,345477],[453883,926476],[392148,878695],
[471772,771547],[339375,590100],[110499,619323],[8713,291093],
[268241,283247],[160815,621452],[168922,810532],[355051,377247],
[10461,488835],[220598,261326],[403537,438947],[221492,640708],
[114702,926457],[166567,477230],[856127,882961],[218411,256327],
[184364,909088],[130802,828793],[312028,811716],[294638,839683],
[269329,343517],[167968,391811],[25351,369583],[210660,454598],
[166834,576380],[296440,873280],[660142,822072],[33441,778393],
[456500,955635],[59220,954158],[306295,429913],[110402,448322],
[44523,88192],[231386,353197],[120940,902781],[348758,597599],
[329467,664450],[208411,890114],[230238,516885],[434113,602358],
[349759,419831],[10689,308144],[94526,180723],[435280,986655],
[611999,690154],[75208,395348],[403243,489260],[498884,611075],
[487209,863242],[13900,873774],[656706,782943],[53478,586952],
[226216,723114],[554799,922759],[467777,689913],[80630,147482],
[277803,506346],[532240,976029],[206622,761192],[148277,985819],
[10879,807349],[952227,971268],[172074,919866],[239230,384499],
[607687,984661],[4405,264532],[41071,437502],[432603,661142],
[144398,907360],[139605,360037],[943191,997317],[12894,171584],
[382477,800157],[452077,518175],[208007,398880],[375250,489928],
[384503,726837],[278181,628759],[114470,635575],[382297,733713],
[156559,874172],[507016,815520],[164461,532215],[17332,536971],
[418721,911117],[11497,14032]]
```

Comment: I guess an add-on question is why it was still able to pass 66/77 tests. Why did the error not pop out in the first place?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have a vector of vectors? It rarely makes a sense to represent a pair of values as std::vector.

Comment: @n.m. i dont know. Leetcode uses that.

Comment: Leetcode is, to put it mildly, not an epitome of quality coding.

Comment: @n.m. what i meant is Leetcode defines the function signature as vector of vectors, so if I change it to some other type. The function won't run.

Answer (score 4):

The comparator to `sort` should return a boolean (i.e true or false). Your condition should thus be:

```
a[0] < b[0]
```

Comment: oh, i see. So that's the issue!

Comment: I was thinking this as a compare to function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But why was it still able to pass 66/77 tests? Why did the error not pop out in the first place?

Comment: @Nat Because the result of `a[0] - b[0]` is an integer, which can be converted into a boolean depending on whether the number is zero or non-zero. Also, `std::sort` requires that your comparison function follow a [strict-weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Since your function does not, this will cause something calling Undefined Behavior. The compiler doesn't need to give you an error or warning or anything when your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation:p